# Malformed Json Exception in Prod Env

Tags: java, json

I am converting response string to JSON Element using below code but in PROD I see MalformedJsonException but with same code base no issue is seen in UAT or DEV.
How can I resolve this issue in PROD env or how to find what went wrong in PROD.

I verified response string with UAT and PROD no difference. Verified JSON response check if an extra ‘}’ using JSON lint it show json is valid.

How can I fix it.

Below code I am using to convert to JSON Element.

```
public jsonElement parsejsonContentFromStream (Inputstream in){
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (in));
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
return parser.parse(bufferedReader);
```

}

Exception is at

```
return parser.parse(bufferedReader);
```

Comment: It may be the character encoding that differs (if the JSON is the same?). When you create your InputStreamReader it uses the default encoding for the server. Either add an argument and specify the encoding (most likely UTF-8) or pass the InputStream directly to the JsonParser if it supports that and let it figure out the encoding from the content. If you know the encoding, specifying it up front is the safest bet!

Comment: How can I specify the encoding? 
I can not pass input stream directly I should use either String.valueOf(in) or by using bufferedReader

Comment: See Debanjan's answer below. I would use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 instead of Charset.forName though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the required charset while creating your `InputStreamReader` and then use that to create the `BufferedReader`.

```
public jsonElement parsejsonContentFromStream (Inputstream in){
  Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, inputCharset);
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (isr);
  JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
  return parser.parse(bufferedReader);
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried as suggested using StandardCharsets.UTF_8 but string is coming in different format instead of string object. And throwing exception. not a JSON object

Expected: {“response”:[{“portfolio:”12345”,”id”:”555555”}]}.      Actual:  “\u001f<\b\u0000\u000”

Comment: @ewramner can you pls help me here.